# The vertical line in Schrodinger equation: What is the pronunciation and function of it?

Tags: notation

How do you pronounce the vertical line in the middle of the Schrodinger equation? Simply "vertical line"? And in the end of the equation, there is a bent vertical line like >. How do you pronounce it? Plus, the Hamiltonian operator H has a cap on it, how do you pronounce it? I have noticed that some teachers write the equation without the vertical lines (including the bent line), which appears to be easier to understand. I don't know why the lines are inserted here and what functions they have.

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: It's called a [ket](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation) as in bra-ket.

Comment: As for the carat over the $H$, this is typically pronounced "hat". So you would read $\hat{H}$ as "H hat"

Comment: You don't pronounce them, usually. $\vert\psi\rangle$ is just pronounced "psi". The purpose of the notation only becomes clear once you are introduced to the linear algebraic approach to quantum mechanics. In this formalism, we consider wave functions as representations of the physical state which is encoded as a vector in a vector space equipped with an inner product. There, we often need to calculate inner products of such states, which we write as $\langle\phi\vert\psi\rangle$. Some mathematical operations are now very conventiently expressed if we write states as $\vert\psi\rangle$.

Comment: The replies helped. Thanks a lot.